# ggplot2 graph x axis and line labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am using this data
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqt7bdhzlwdsxl2/summary_exp1.csv

And the following code:

```
pd <- position_dodge(.1)
ggplot(data=summary.200.exp1, aes(x=Time, y=Length, colour=Genotype, group=Genotype)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Length - se, ymax=Length + se), colour="black", width=.1,         position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Genotype),position=pd, size=3) +
  ylab("leaf segment width (mm)") +
  xlab("Time") +
   theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14,face="bold"), 
        axis.text = element_text(size=14),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=14))
```

I need to make the following modifications:

1. Adjust the x-axis limits to eliminate the spaces between the y-axis and the data plotted at `time0` and then between `Time22` and the edge of the graph. I have looked at documentation and tried this: 
   `scale_x_discrete(limits=c("0","22"))`, but it doesn't work.
2. Modify labelling so that each line on the graph is labelled with a distinct colour, the "Genotype" and the legend is eliminated. For this I have tried various options with   `geom_text(aes(colour=Genotype))`, which I also cannot get to work.

I would appreciate any help with this.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can eliminate the space between the plot and the axis by adding `expand = c(0, 0)` to the scale parameter:`scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))`
2. You can eliminate the legend by adding `show_guide=FALSE` to e.g. the `geom_line` part of your code.

---

EDIT:

I think your are trying to plot to much into one graph. The errorbars, for example, overlap each other to much to get a readable plot. Using facets might be a good idea in this case (in my opinion). the following code (in which named the dataframe as `dat`):

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Time, y=Length, colour=Genotype)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Genotype), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,17,15,8,13,6,12,4)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Length-se, ymax=Length+se, colour=Genotype), width=.2) +
  guides(colour=FALSE, shape=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Genotype, ncol=4)
```

results in this plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jaap, much appreciated. Do you have any help with how to get the labelling (I am assuming geom_text is needed, but the graph disappears when I use the code I explained above in #2). Also, when I use show_guide = FALSE as you suggested, I get two genotype symbols disappearing (CD and RIL4), but the text remains in the legend and the other symbols remain in the legend.

Comment: The reason for the disappearing symbols is that the `shape` scale can only deal with 6 discrete values. If you have more, you need to specify them manually. Moreover I think it is wise in your case to use facets. See my updated answer.